# replace blank column with word

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have a text file some of the record is blank and I want replace that blank space with the word N/A or null

ex-

```
field-A  field-b  field-c   field-d   field-e  field-f  field-g  field-h   field-i
1           2       3          4      5           6     7           8          9 

1                   3          4      5           6      7          8          9

            2       3          4      5           6      7          8          9

1                               4     5           6      7          8          9
```

result expect

```
field-A  field-b  field-c   field-d   field-e  field-f  field-g  field-h   field-i
1           2       3          4      5           6     7           8          9 

1          N/A      3          4      5           6      7          8          9

N/A         2       3          4      5           6      7          8          9

1          N/A     N/A         4     5            6      7          8          9
```

Comment: How will you know which column is missing - as it appears you don't have any consistent delimiters

Comment: @cbz maybe it's homework, and there are always 9 numbers from 1 to 9

Comment: sorry! the format on web page didn't display the white space I made. but when 1345.. that means 2 is missing which is blank

Comment: reformatted - please rollback if I am clobbering the original intent of the question instead of clarifying it

Comment: @dan, are the fields separated with a particular character (i.e. tab) or is it just "whitespace". It's simple to find empty fields with tab-separated columns, but it's hard to determine how many empty fields exist with there's just a bunch of spaces between data.

Comment: I have converted the file to csv  which is now separated with comma (,)is that better?  how is that work on csv? thx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a space character I'd look for the character code or a blank space.

In C# assuming your variable was `mystr` it would be something like:

`myStr = myStr.Replace(" ", "N/A");`

You can also look for the character value, depending on the language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/  / x / while /  /' <<END
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1  3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1   4 5 6 7 8 9
END
```

produces

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 x 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 x 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 x x 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. with your command x replace all white space. I want only replace missing data with "x" the result is on column. let say column 1,3 blank so I want replace with "X" may be specify column number make easy??